# MySQL selecting columns from a specific table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm learning MySQL and this is probably the most basic of the basic questions I could ask, but I want to make sure I understand the syntax.

I have a MySQL script that created three different databases. If I wanted to select all fields from a specific database's table, I would use

```
SELECT * from database1.table1
```

correct? Or would it just be

```
SELECT * from table1
```

and if I wanted to select only two fields from another table, would it be

```
SELECT field1, field2 from database1.table2
```

or again just the table name?

Comment: Look into `USE dbName;` statement. If you already selected a db,which many clients do by default, there is no need to specify the db

Comment: it depends on whether or not if you have specified a database. if yes, then you don't need to specify the database you already specified in the query statement. otherwise you do.

Comment: if I'm just sticking these commands inside the script after the databases are created, which would I use?

Comment: Both would be fine,the advantage of USE db is that you dont have to specify the db for each statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both forms are actually fine. In SQL you can qualify names to specify explicitly where a db object is located. This is useful for instance if you have a table2 in 2 different schemas (which is the correct term instead of "database", btw).

As it has been mentioned you can set a default schema to avoid having to add a schema to a reference (like your table2) all the time. If there is no schema given then the default schema (set with the `USE schema` command) will be taken instead. You still can use an explicit schema (either what is set as default or any other) if you like. This will help when you want to access an object which is not in the default schema.